# jest unknown coverage with jenkins, works fine on local

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jestjs

When i run my jest test script present in package.json on local machine, tests run and give code coverage as expected.

But when same script is executed from jennkins, tests run but coverage show
"unknown" result as shown below :

```html
20:58:23 =============================== Coverage summary ===============================
20:58:23 Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
20:58:23 Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
20:58:23 Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
20:58:23 Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
20:58:23 ================================================================================
20:58:23 Test Suites: 15 passed, 15 total
20:58:23 Tests:       37 passed, 37 total
20:58:23 Snapshots:   0 total
20:58:23 Time:        9.106s
20:58:23 Ran all test suites.
```

Below is my jest config file :

```js
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfigFile: 'tsconfig.json'
        }
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'ts',
        'js'
    ],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    testMatch: [
        '**/__tests__/**/*.(ts|js)',
        '**/src/**/*.spec.(ts|js)'
    ],
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/',
        '/coverage/',
        '/support/cacerts/',
        '/support/certs/',
        '/dist/',
        '/jenkins/',
        '/config/',
        '/logs/'
    ],
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageReporters: [
        'cobertura',
        'html'
    ],
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        '**/src/**/*.{ts,js}',
        '!**/src/**/*.spec.{ts,js}',
        '!**/node_modules/**'
    ],
    coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage",
    coverageThreshold: {
        'global': {
            'branches': 60,
            'functions': 60,
            'lines': 60,
            'statements': 80
        }
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'ts',
        'js'
    ]
};
```

Comment: any update on this issue?I am also getting the same